# Intrinsic Camera Parameter Matrix is not always same after calibrated the camera several times

Tags: c#, emgucv, camera-calibration

I made a camera calibration application following the emgu cv wiki tutorial in C#.
when I run the code several times, each time the intrinsic camera parameter matrix s different to the previous ones. Here I didn't change the camera orientation and neither the image plane. Camera setup is fixed as shown in the image CameraSetup.jpg in the following link.
[CameraSetup.jpg](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hic8i59s7hhiuwx/AACM87EI_hrGvE2ixsQ7NTlAa?dl=0)

My code is as follows. I have no idea how to proceed further.
Regards!

```js
namespace CameraCallibration
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        #region variables

        Capture capture = new Capture(1);

        int bufferIndex;

        const int width = 9;//9 //width of chessboard no. squares in width - 1
        const int height = 6;//6 // heght of chess board no. squares in heigth - 1
        Size patternSize = new Size(width, height); //size of chess board to be detected

        Bgr[] line_colour_array = new Bgr[width * height]; // just for displaying coloured lines of detected chessboard
        static Image<Gray, Byte>[] Frame_array_buffer = new Image<Gray, byte>[100];
        MCvPoint3D32f[][] corners_object_list = new MCvPoint3D32f[Frame_array_buffer.Length][];
        PointF[][] corners_points_list = new PointF[Frame_array_buffer.Length][];

        IntrinsicCameraParameters IC = new IntrinsicCameraParameters();
        ExtrinsicCameraParameters[] EX_Param;

        enum mode
        {
            SavingFrames,
            Caluculating_Intrinsics,
            Calibrated
        };

        mode currentMode = new mode();

        #endregion

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Interval = 10;
            currentMode = mode.SavingFrames;
            bufferIndex = 0;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Image<Bgr, Byte> BgrFrame = capture.QueryFrame();
            imageBox1.Image = BgrFrame.Resize(320, 240, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_NN);

            Image<Gray, Byte> GrayFrame = BgrFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
            imageBox2.Image = GrayFrame.Resize(320, 240, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_NN);

            if(currentMode == mode.SavingFrames)
            {
                Frame_array_buffer[bufferIndex] = GrayFrame.Copy();
                bufferIndex++;

                if(bufferIndex == Frame_array_buffer.Length)
                {
                    currentMode = mode.Caluculating_Intrinsics;
                    textBox1.Text = "Frames Saved";
                    timer1.Enabled = false;
                }
            }

            if(currentMode == mode.Caluculating_Intrinsics)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < Frame_array_buffer.Length ; i++)
                {
                    corners_points_list[i] = CameraCalibration.FindChessboardCorners(GrayFrame, patternSize, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CALIB_CB_TYPE.ADAPTIVE_THRESH);

                    List<MCvPoint3D32f> object_list = new List<MCvPoint3D32f>();
                   
                    for(int j = 0; j < height; j++)
                    {
                        for(int k = 0; k < width; k++)
                        {
                            object_list.Add(new MCvPoint3D32f(k * 20.0F, j * 20.0F, 0.0F));
                        }
                    }

                    corners_object_list[i] = object_list.ToArray();
                }

                double difError =  CameraCalibration.CalibrateCamera(corners_object_list, corners_points_list, GrayFrame.Size, IC, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CALIB_TYPE.CV_CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL,out EX_Param);

                currentMode = mode.Calibrated;
                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox1.Text = "Calculated";
            }

            if(currentMode == mode.Calibrated)
            {
                //calculate the camera intrinsics
                Matrix<Single> Map1, Map2;
                IC.InitUndistortMap(BgrFrame.Width,BgrFrame.Height,out Map1,out Map2);
                //remap the image to the particular intrinsics
                //In the current version of EMGU any pixel that is not corrected is set to transparent allowing the original image to be displayed if the same
                //image is mapped backed, in the future this should be controllable through the flag '0'
                Image<Bgr, Byte> temp = BgrFrame.CopyBlank();
                CvInvoke.cvRemap(BgrFrame, temp, Map1, Map2,0,new MCvScalar(0) );
                imageBox3.Image = temp.Resize(320,240,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_NN);
                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox1.Text = "Calibrated";

                Matrix<double> IntrParaMat = IC.IntrinsicMatrix;

                for(int i =0 ; i < IntrParaMat.Rows ; i++)
                {
                    for(int j =0 ; j < IntrParaMat.Cols; j++)
                    {
                        textBox2.Text += Convert.ToString( IntrParaMat[i, j]) + "  ";
                    }
                    textBox2.Text += Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                timer1.Enabled = true;
                button1.Enabled = false; 
        }
}
```

Comment: What are the variations for the intrinsic parameters, for example if you run your code ten times you will get ten different values for the focal length, what is the mean and the standard deviation of these ten values?

Comment: for example values for fx has the range between 180 and 8050. In this code, I used images buffered from live feed of the camera. Hence all the images have the same orientation. Will this affect the above deviation?

Comment: from 180 to 8050 does not look good. Can you post images of the chessboard as taken from the camera? Maybe the problem lies in the results computed by `FindChessboardCorners`.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it is autofocus. when calibrating camera disable autofocus. Also ensure you have at least 20 images.